# GameObject is unresponsive on load

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've got a Unity VR project that I'm working on but I'm having issues with throwable projectiles.
It was just working perfectly fine, the only issue I was having was that it was not sending damage.  Now when I click play to test it, **the object just doesn't do anything**.  The projectile is just a game object with a few components and a few child particle systems inside for visuals but not even those show up.

My script also has some explosion physics which was working fine until this weird issue where the object just chooses to not exist.

I am using the VR Interaction Framework from Bearded Ninja Games for most of the interactions and my projectile script interacts with the Damageable type from the framework.  (It's a brilliant framework to jump start a VR project)

[Component setup for the projectile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJFq1.png)

**Projectile Script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace BNG{

    public class MagicProjectiles : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float effectRadius = 5f;
        public float physicsStrength = 100f;
        public float baseDamage = 20f;
        public float statModifier = 20f;
        public float Damage;

        void Start()
        {
            SphereCollider collider = GetComponent("SphereCollider") as SphereCollider;
            Damage = baseDamage + (baseDamage * statModifier / 100);
        }

        void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            Debug.Log("Exploding");
            Rigidbody projectile = GetComponent("Rigidbody") as Rigidbody;
            Vector3 explosionPos = transform.position;
            Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(explosionPos, effectRadius);
            foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
            {
                //Debug.Log(hit);
                Rigidbody objectHit = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                Damageable damageable = hit.GetComponent<Damageable>();
                if (objectHit != null)
                {
                    objectHit.AddExplosionForce(physicsStrength, explosionPos, effectRadius, 3.0f);
                    if (damageable)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Sending " + Damage + " Damage to " + damageable);
                        damageable.DealDamage(Damage, collision.GetContact(0).point, collision.GetContact(0).normal, true, gameObject, collision.gameObject);
                    }
                    Destroy(this, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unity does not give me any errors for this script.

**What I have tried:**

- Restarting Unity
- Restoring the script to a point where it was working correctly
- Putting the script onto another game object

**Updated**:
I tried using a backup of my projectile prefab from before I even added the projectile script and not even that is working.

**Updated**:
I created a new Unity project, copied over the projectile prefab along with the script and it works perfectly fine.  This only made me more confused

Comment: Does it cease to exist in the scene view or the hierarchy as well? Maybe it is destroyed pre-maturely? (you could check this by logging something in its `void OnDestroy()` function)

Comment: @Meowmere
I wish it was just pre-maturely destroying the object, but it stays in the hierarchy and does nothing.  I even removed the `Destroy()` function just to be sure.  There's another projectile that uses the exact same script and when I loaded that one in, one of the particle systems for it loaded.  That's all.

Comment: I couldn't fix the issue so I just started a new unity project, imported all of my assets and now it's working again.  Really not sure what happened.